# Yasm ebe How to Add to an Indexed Value of an Array

Tags: arrays, nasm, addition, opcode, yasm

[First Part of the Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHsC.png)

[Second Part of the Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfsft.png)

Hello! I am confused on how to add to a value of an array in ebe. I've tried some different ways, but all resulted in an error that stated: "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

```
        segment .data
a       dw      -4, 22, 144
b       db      -3, -16, 12
c       dw      -3
result  dq      0

         segment .text
         global main
main:
    add     a, c
    ret
```

This was one of my attempts, I am trying to add -3 to an indexed value of array a, but I am just stuck on how to actually do this. Please help!

Comment: There's no memory-to-memory `add`. You'll have to load at least one of the operands into a register.

Comment: So would that mean I would need to do something along the lines of:  lea  rax, [a] then would I be able to add [a], [c]. Or would I need to also do something to c?